# Rerender based on SelectOption value on CommandButton Click

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, selectlist

I have a visualforce page with a SelectList (with 3 select options) and a Command Button.
Based on the selectList value chosen, I want to rerender few outputPanels below.  Below are the complete details with code.

Here is the Visualforce Page code

```
<apex:page controller="SupplierSnapshotChartSelection" title="Chart Selection Page" sidebar="false" >
<apex:messages />

<apex:form >
<apex:panelGrid columns="2">
<apex:selectList value="{!ChartNames}" required="True">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!ChartItems}" />
</apex:selectList> 
<br/> 
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Chart" reRender="Results" action="{!ChartGenerate}"/>
</apex:panelGrid>

<apex:outputPanel id="Results" >
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ChartNames=='Pie Chart'}">
    <apex:pageblock title="Suppliers" ><!-- DETAILS --></apex:pageblock> 
<apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class

```
public String[] ChartNames = new String[]{};    
public String[] getChartNames() {return ChartNames;}

public void setChartNames(String[] ChartNames) {
    this.ChartNames = ChartNames;
}

public  List<SelectOption> getChartItems() {
     List<SelectOption> ChartOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
     ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Line Chart','Line Chart'));
     ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Bar Chart Vertical','Bar Chart Vertical')); 
     ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Pie Chart','Pie Chart'));  
     return ChartOptions;                       
}
```

What could be error? Please let me know.  Thanks much

Comment: Are you seeing an error message? What is currently happening? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Currently nothing is rendered.  If i remove the condition rendered="{!ChartNames=='Pie Chart'}"> then the ouput panel renders correctly.  But I want to render only if the above condition satisfies.

Comment: Your page markup is missing closing tags for the apex:outputPanel. Can you update it so it is valid?

Comment: Im now getting an error message when i added <apex:pageMessages> in the VF page

`Unknownproperty 'SupplierSnapshotChartSelection.ChartNames'`

Comment: Add a getChartNames property

Comment: Do you intend ChartNames to be a multi-select or a single picklist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that {!ChartNames=='Pie Chart'} will never be true because you've declared it not as a String but as an array of type String. Here I've changed it to just be a public String property and I also added the missing ChartGenerate action:

```
public with sharing class SupplierSnapshotChartSelection {

    public String ChartNames {get; set;}    

    public  List<SelectOption> getChartItems() {
         List<SelectOption> ChartOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Line Chart','Line Chart'));
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Bar Chart Vertical','Bar Chart Vertical')); 
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Pie Chart','Pie Chart'));  
         return ChartOptions;                       
    }

    public PageReference ChartGenerate() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now it works fine with this VF (note you didn't have a valid closing of your outputPanel at the bottom)

```
<apex:page controller="SupplierSnapshotChartSelection" title="Chart Selection Page" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:messages />

    <apex:form >
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:selectList value="{!ChartNames}" required="True">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ChartItems}" />
        </apex:selectList> 
        <br/> 
        <apex:commandButton value="Generate Chart" reRender="Results" action="{!ChartGenerate}"/>
        </apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:outputPanel id="Results" >
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ChartNames=='Pie Chart'}">
                <apex:pageblock title="Suppliers" ><!-- DETAILS --></apex:pageblock> 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

You could eliminate the chartGenerate action and the commandButton by utilizing actionSupport with an onChange Event. That can simplify things down to this:

Controller:

```
public with sharing class SupplierSnapshotChartSelection {

    public String ChartNames {get; set;}    

    public  List<SelectOption> getChartItems() {
         List<SelectOption> ChartOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('','-- Select One --'));
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Line Chart','Line Chart'));
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Bar Chart Vertical','Bar Chart Vertical')); 
         ChartOptions.add(new SelectOption('Pie Chart','Pie Chart'));  
         return ChartOptions;                       
    }
}
```

VF

```
<apex:page controller="SupplierSnapshotChartSelection" title="Chart Selection Page" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:selectList value="{!ChartNames}" required="True" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!ChartItems}" />
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Results"/>
        </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:outputPanel id="Results" >
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!ChartNames=='Pie Chart'}">
                <apex:pageblock title="Suppliers" ><!-- DETAILS --></apex:pageblock> 
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Yes, changing the array of string to just a string worked well.  Thanks much.